# ADFS add wtrealm/wres parameter to signout call for claims provider

Tags: adfs

I'am trying to signout from our claims provider with wsfed.
Our Claims Provider (Identity Server 4) needs to identify which client it is.
Unfortunate ADFS does not send a wtrealm or wres parameter.

Is there a way to tell ADFS to include one of these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

•   According to the wsignin1.0 request message, the ‘wtrealm’ parameter is included in the request message to a different security realm, i.e., federated platform which trusts AD domain attributes for signing and accessibility purposes on its platform from the relying party trust created in the ADFS Server. This value is present as a URI that the SaaS platform and the IdP, i.e., the relying party trust have agreed to use to identify the security realm of the relying party in messages to the requestor SaaS platform or STS.

•   Thus, to configure or change the ‘wtrealm’ parameter that is passed in the URI of the requestor communication message, follow the steps below: -

1. Open the ADFS Management Console and click on the ‘Actions’ menu in the task bar.
2. Right click the ADFS option and click ‘Edit Federation Properties’. The federation service properties window is displayed.
3. Select the ‘Federation Service Identifier’ option and edit the value of the domain/STS/IP/client with which the trust is configured for.

•   As this value of ‘Federation Service Identifier’ only is the value of the ‘wtrealm’ parameter in the request message URI sent during signin and signout to and from the IdP and the security realm or federated SaaS platform. Also, you can check whether supporting multiple federated domains is supported in your ADFS server or not if you are encountering an issue with signing into the federated platform. For that purpose, also you can configure the relying party federation trust to support multiple domains by updating them using the ‘-supportmultipledomain’ switch as given in the example below: -

```
 ‘ Update-MSOLFederatedDomain -DomainName <Federated Domain Name> -supportmultipledomain ’
```

Please find the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-mwbf/54759c9b-4298-44f7-9026-f5ee815594d8

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/federation-service-identifier-specified

Comment: Sorry forgot to accept your answer. Thank you for helping